# Pasar script a funcion

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de pasar un código a un función para poder llamarlo de la misma. El script cumple la función de transformar un texto en negrita o itali utilizando `*` para negrita y `_` para itali.

El problema es que al pasarlo no me funciona, tampoco me arroja error alguno, simplemente el texto no se ve y no se que esta mal. Agradezco de antemano.

```
<?php
    function ($text) {
        //italicas
        $pattern = '/(_(.*?)_)/';
        $replace = '<em>${2}</em>';
        $text = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text); 

        //negritas
        $pattern = '/(\*(.*?)\*)/';
        $replace = '<strong>${2}</strong>';
        $text = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text); 
    }

    $prueba = '*texto con negrita*, texto natural y *_texto con negrita e itali_*';

    echo $text($prueba);
?>
```

Comment: Primero revisa bien tu pregunta pk en el codigo el * es para la italic y el _ es para la negrita. Segundo si para armar una compuesta comienzas por la negrita, cuando hace el replace, pierdes el _ de la italic. Entonces o comienzas primero con el reemplazo de la italic en tu codigo y despues por la negrita o haces un replace con expresiones regulares del compuesto primero que las que tienes. Ejemplo reemplazas *_ por <strong><em> y _* por <em><strong>

Comment: Ya lo modifique...

Comment: Te falta el return de la función y un nombre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero que debes hacer es asignarle un nombre a la función y ejecutarla con ese nombre, luego de esto debes retornar desde la función el texto ya transformado para que se pueda imprimir en el `echo`:

```
<?php
    function transformar($text) {
        //negritas
        $pattern = '/(_(.*?)_)/';
        $replace = '<em>${2}</em>';
        $text = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text); 

        //italicas
        $pattern = '/(\*(.*?)\*)/';
        $replace = '<strong>${2}</strong>';
        $text = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text); 

        return $text;
    }

    $prueba = '*texto con negrita*, texto natural y *_texto con negrita e itali_*';

    echo transformar($prueba);
?>
```

Dando como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que sucede si el ultimo texto lo pongo de esta manera: `_*texto con negrita e itali*_ ` ???

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas funciona igual...

Answer (score 0):

En tu **función** te falta `return $text;` para poder obtener el valor del **string** modificado.